# PHP X MYSQL | Error in Injecting data using $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to input data from $_Post variables but I cannot spot where the error is? Hope you can help me. 
Below is the code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
if (isset($_POST['studLog'])) {
 $uName = $_POST['uName'];
 $pWord = $_POST['pWord'];

 mysql_select_db("sis_main", $conn);

 if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from student where stud_uname='$uName' and stud_pword='$pWord'"))) {
  include("stud-view.html");
 } else {
  echo 'Account doesnt exist!';
  echo "<br><br>";
  echo "<a href='stud-start.html'>GO BACK!</a>";
 }
} else if (isset($_POST['studReg'])) {

 mysql_select_db("sis_main", $conn);
 $stdID = $_POST['studID'];
 $fname = $_POST['firstNme'];
 $mname = $_POST['midNme'];
 $lname = $_POST['lastNme'];
 $stadd = $_POST['stAdd'];
 $ctadd = $_POST['ctAdd'];
 $bdate = $_POST['bDate'];
 $gendr = $_POST['gender'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $mobno = $_POST['mobNum'];
 $uname = $_POST['newUName'];
 $pword = $_POST['newPWord'];
 $age = birthday($bdate);

 if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO student values (`$stdID`,`$fname`,`$lname`, `$mname`,`$stadd`,`$ctadd`,`$age`,`$bdate`,`$gendr`, `$email`,`$mobno`,`$uname`,`$pword`);")) {
  echo 'Account Successfully Regsitered!';
 } else {
  echo 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
  echo "<a href='stud-start.html'>GO BACK!</a>";
 }


}
}
```

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, 09981744039, kuyschan, kuyschan)' at line 1

Comment: a) use parameterized statements. to protect yourself from **SQL Injection** and most SQL syntax errors. b) **don't** use deprecated `mysql`-functions, use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. c) **never ever ever** store unhashed passwords, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: describe table.what is datatype of "email" column.?

Comment: thank you for your feedback! The email column is varchar(30)

Comment: It think it's a textbook example of (involuntary) SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

This is suppposed to be a comment, but i have a low reputation here.

Before i answer your question, please do not use the mysql functions as its no longer supported . Consider a switch to either MYSQLI or PDO. Also, do not trust user input. Meaning do not directly post field values from your form to your database as an attcker can easily exploit it by adding funny javascripts or worse.

To your question,

In your insert statement, you did not specify the columns:

Try:

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO student  (`studID`, `firstNme`, `lastNme`,`stAdd`,`ctAdd`,`bDate`,`gender`,`email`,`mobNum`,`newUName`,`newPWord`)VALUES 
 ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['studID']) . "', 
 '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstNme']) . "', 
 '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastNme']) . "', 
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['stAdd']) . "', 
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ctAdd']) . "',     
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bDate']) . "', 
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']) . "', 
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']) . "', 
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mobNum']) . "', 
'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['newUName']) . "',     
 '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['newPWord']) . "')";
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

$conn->close();

Where $con is your database connection.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Or, if you aren't being paid by typed character, you can just use prepared statements ;-)

Comment: yeah you right. I just gave this answer as a workaround for this specific scenario :)